# What are the components on this schematics?

Tags: sensor, relay

[image: it is a diagram with pir and a motor]

I would like to know the name of the components of this circuit.

I want to build an automatic door system.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the basic names of the components:

[image]

More detailed information is available at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_component, and The MOSFET's data sheet is at: 
http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlml2502.pdf

Comment: Also, please pay close attention to the fact that the symbol for the IRLML2502 is wrong. FYI, the relay will be connected to the drain, the comparator to the gate, and the source is grounded.